# Why do we need to sprinkle water on cotton clothes before ironing/pressing them?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, physical-chemistry

Many a times, cotton garments need water to be sprinkled upon them before pressing or ironing. Without water, these clothes cannot be properly pressed by a hot iron. Steam iron can be used as an alternative. But some type of moisture is needed, otherwise the garments remain shrivelled. Why?

Comment: First paragraph of the wikipedia page on Ironing addresses these questions directly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironing see what you think

Comment: The reason is actually nothing to do with physics and everything to do with biochemistry. Water helps to break down the bonds between cotton fibres through hydrolysis.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about physics.

Comment: The water gets absorbed into the polymer (cotton is comprised of polymeric molecules) and acts as a plasticizer, allowing the polymer molecules to become more mobile and relax, thus erasing the memory of the fibers to their prior crimped configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I quote the answer by Wrichik Basu. But I add that ironing has to do, rather than with hydrolysis of fibers as suggested in comments (lifetime of items would be very short) with the breaking of H bonds.

Is very similar to hair dressing.

The use of water has the effect of "hydrolisying" such H bonds in addition to enhance thermal conduction to supply energy for the above breaking of bonds.

Comment: Good input. Although I don't know anything about hair dressing, the hydrolysis is a good point.

Comment: @wrichik Basu. Actually I do not like the term hydrolysis here. There is not hydrolysis of fibers. Just breaking of H bonds by heat. Water helps by the mechanism you suggest plus it intercalates by forming its bonds to the cellulose. Curly hairs: lots of H bonds. Hairdryer: breaking of those bonds and flattening.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason (according to me) is that, cotton is a bad conductor of heat. As a result, the heat from the iron does not get evenly distributed throughout the fabric. So, some parts of the fabric get the heat, while other parts do not, which is why they remain shrivelled.

Sprinkling water on the clothes causes absorption of these molecules of water in between the strands of fabric (aided by capillary action and the cohesive nature of water). When heat is applied, the molecules of water absorb this heat and evenly distributed them throughout the fabric. Thus, the clothes can be properly pressed.

Steam ejected from steam iron does the same thing, but in a different way. In case of water, the water absorbs the heat and evenly distributes it throughout the material. But steam is itself heated. The hot gas is forced through the fabric, which distributes heat throughout the cloth.

This is my explanation. Anyone who has a different explanation can freely put in their opinions as additional answers.

Comment: The real reason is that water is needed for hydrolysis of the cotton fibres.

Comment: I was unaware about hydrolysis. Thanks for pointing that out.